# "Files" app not loading sandobox of application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sandbox, ios14

I have problem with Apple "Files" application.
Application "Files" sometimes is not loading app Sandbox right after i saved and i loaded image from there. "Files" has only indicator and it loading forever and never ends.

Getting Image:

```
static func getImage(from directory: String, fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
    let dirUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent(directory).appendingPathComponent(name + ".jpeg")
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dirUrl.path) {
        let data = dirUrl.dataRepresentation
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Saving Image:

```
static func save(_ image: UIImage, name: String, directory: String) {
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            .appendingPathComponent(directory)
            .appendingPathComponent(name)
        do {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: url.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if let data = image.resized(withPercentage: 0.5)?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.25) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: url )
                
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Also i was trying with option `.atomic`, `.atomicWrite` but it doesn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem since Xcode 12. Did you find any Solution?